# Retrieving and manipulating data from file

Tags: file-io, vector

The following code is supposed to retrieve the data related to the players info, sort it out and then rewrite the file now organized. Going to give an example of the files.

Original layout:

```
     3
  2  2

                John  33 M     5
                Anna  20 F     2
                Rody  23 M     1
```

What it has to look like after the code:

```
     3
  2  2

                Rody  23 M     1
                Anna  20 F     2
                John  33 M     5
```

I made the following code:

```
vector<string> playerScoresFromFile(const string filename) //Gets each one of those lines with the name, ..., and score of the person
{
int dim = filename[7] - '0'; // char to integer
vector<string> vec;
string line;

ifstream fin (filename.c_str());


for (int i = 0; i < dim + 1; i++)
{
    getline(fin, line);
}

while(! fin.eof())
{   
    getline(fin, line);
    vec.push_back(line);
}

return vec;
}


vector< vector<int> > readBoardFromFile(const string filename) //gets the board from the file (first 3 numbers)
{
int dim = filename[7] - '0'; // char to integer
string line;
vector< vector<int> >vec(dim, vector<int>(dim));

ifstream fin (filename.c_str());

int i = 0;
int j, k;
while(i < dim)
{
    getline(fin, line);
    int sizeOfLine = line.length();

    if (line[0] == '\0')
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        for (j = 0, k = 0; j < (sizeOfLine / 3); j++, k += 3)
        {
            string elementOfVectorStr = (line.substr(k,3));
            int elementOfVectorInt = stringToInt(elementOfVectorStr);
            if (abs(elementOfVectorInt) > 100) // when the element is a " ", the corresponding integer is always
            {                                  // a very large number, positive or negative
                elementOfVectorInt = 0;
            }
            vec[i][j] = elementOfVectorInt;
        }
    }
    i++;
}

return vec;
}


vector<string> sortPlayersByTime (vector<string> &vec) // Creates a substring of the string extracted by "playerScoresFromFile" and analyses the times (Which are the last numbers to the right)
{
vector<int> timesInt(vec.size());

for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    string str = vec[i];
    timesInt[i] = stringToInt(str.substr(26));
}


for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; i++)
{
    if(timesInt[i] > timesInt[i+1])
    {
        swap(vec[i], vec[i+1]);
    }
}

return vec;
}



bool isOrdered (const vector<string> vec)  //Checks if the vector is ordered
{
vector<int> timesInt(vec.size());

for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    string str = vec[i];
    timesInt[i] = stringToInt(str.substr(26));
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size() - 1; i++)
{
    if(timesInt[i] > timesInt[i+1])
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
}


void writeBoardToFile(vector< vector<int> >&vec, string filename) //Rewrites the board to the file (Those first 3 numbers of the file)
{
ofstream fout(filename.c_str());

for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < vec.size(); j++)
    {
        if(vec[i][j] != 0)
        {
            fout << setw(3) << vec[i][j];
        }
        else
        {
            fout << setw(3) << " ";
        }
    }

    fout << endl;
}
fout << endl;
}


void vec_to_file(vector<string> vec, string filename) //Rewrites the vector to the file
{

ofstream fout(filename, ios::app);

for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    fout << vec[i] <<endl;
}
}


void displayFile (string filename) //Displays the final board to check if it worked
{
vector<string> vec;
string line;

ifstream myfile (filename);

while ( ! myfile.eof() )
{
    getline (myfile, line);
    vec.push_back(line);
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
{
    cout << vec[i] <<endl;
}

}


int main()
{
    vector< vector<int> > vec = readBoardFromFile("puzzle_2x2_001.txt");

vector<string> vecxz = playerScoresFromFile("puzzle_2x2_001.txt");


writeBoardToFile(vec, "puzzle_2x2_001.txt"); //Writes the board to the file


while (! isOrdered(vecxz))  //This loop should run while they haven't been sorted out, but the program crashes here and I have no idea why.
{
    sortPlayersByTime(vecxz);
}


//vec_to_file(vecxy, "puzzle_2x2_001.txt"); //Should write the vector to the file upon sorting them out successfully.

cin.get();

}
```

My problem is the program crashes everytime it gets to the while(! isOrdered(vecxz)) loop but I have no idea why. Can anyone give me a hand? I'd be thankful :)